# Plot parametric interaction term from GAMM in R

Tags: ggplot2, predict, mgcv, gratia

From my GAMM, I've plotted my parametric interaction term on the response scale, but I'm getting these jagged/spiked predictions in my plots, particularly in the green line [A.]. I'd like to see something more like the second plot [B], where each plot seems a lot smoother. Is this something related to my model, predict(), not enough data, or ggplot, and how can I fix it - if possible? My data is too large to share. Ignore the labels, I'm just copying from a tutorial. I have tried increasing the sample size in "MyData" to 10, and 100, but the problem remains.

**A.**

[image]

**B.**

[image]

```
library(plyr)
library(gratia)
library(ggplot2)

m4 <- bam(empty ~ SL*fZone +
           s(fStation, bs = "re"),
         data = c_neb4, 
         method = 'fREML', 
         discrete = TRUE,
         family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
         select = TRUE,
         gamma = 1.5)


MyData <- ddply(c_neb4, 
                .(SL, fZone, fStation), 
                summarize,
                SL = evenly(SL, n = 1))

#' Specify a value for the random effect Plot. 
MyData$fPlot <-  "NA"


#' Do the actual prediction. Ignore the warning.
P2 <- predict(m4, 
              newdata = MyData, 
              se = TRUE,
              newdata.guaranteed = TRUE,
              exclude = "s(fPlot)" )


#' Convert the predicted values to the scale of the observed data.
MyData$eta <- P2$fit
MyData$Pi  <- exp(MyData$eta) / (1 + exp(MyData$eta))

#' Calculate the SEs on the scale of the observed data.
MyData$se    <- P2$se.fit
MyData$SeUp  <- exp(MyData$eta + 1.96 *MyData$se) / 
  (1 + exp(MyData$eta  + 1.96 *MyData$se))

MyData$SeLo  <- exp(MyData$eta - 1.96 *MyData$se) / 
  (1 + exp(MyData$eta  - 1.96 *MyData$se))

> head(MyData)
   fZone fStation    SL fPlot          eta        Pi        se      SeUp      SeLo
1   West      146  9.28    NA -0.265285021 0.4340650 0.3192834 0.5891640 0.2908869
2   West      123 10.22    NA  0.014991421 0.5037478 0.3273342 0.6584887 0.3482856
3 Rankin      240 11.47    NA  0.079175289 0.5197835 0.4404169 0.7195826 0.3134495
4   West       70 13.26    NA  0.003325549 0.5008314 0.2679914 0.6291539 0.3723993
5   West      168 13.64    NA -0.308523994 0.4234751 0.2652243 0.5526332 0.3039912
6   West       70 14.43    NA -0.043266409 0.4891851 0.2606781 0.6148304 0.3648916


p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_point(data = c_neb4, 
                    aes(y = empty, x = SL),
                    shape = 1, 
                    size = 1)
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(size=15)) + theme_bw()
p <- p + geom_line(data = MyData, 
                   aes(x = SL, 
                       y = Pi, 
                       group = fZone,
                       colour = fZone))
p <- p + geom_ribbon(data = MyData, 
                     aes(x = SL, 
                         ymax = SeUp, 
                         ymin = SeLo,
                         group = fZone,
                         fill = fZone),
                     alpha = 0.5)
p + facet_wrap(. ~ fCYR , scales = "fixed", ncol = 2)
p
```

**UPDATE:** Random samples from data

```
> sample <- MyData[sample(nrow(MyData), 15), ]

> dput(sample)

structure(list(fZone = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Crocodile", "Rankin", 
"West", "Whipray"), class = "factor"), fStation = structure(c(34L, 
3L, 41L, 3L, 69L, 51L, 67L, 10L, 11L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 69L, 17L, 
7L), levels = c("20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "40", "54", "65", 
"67", "68", "70", "71", "73", "101", "105", "106", "107", "111", 
"112", "117", "118", "119", "122", "123", "124", "130", "133", 
"134", "135", "137", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "156", 
"157", "158", "159", "167", "168", "169", "171", "172", "173", 
"174", "175", "176", "224", "225", "226", "227", "229", "237", 
"239", "240", "241", "253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "265", 
"266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "278", "279", "280", "281", 
"282", "284", "290", "291", "292", "294", "301", "302", "303", 
"304", "312", "313", "315", "323", "609", "619", "621", "622"
), class = "factor"), SL = c(21.78, 43.7, 22.93, 33.04, 25.27, 
36.44, 41.77, 38.74, 28.67, 43.66, 19.52, 24.88, 34.64, 42.31, 
25.4), fPlot = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), eta = c(-0.763062357276118, 
-1.42419453038225, -0.678472110266059, -0.999690017882061, -0.603965123351189, 
-1.36501523925482, -2.37609726046486, -1.08785823464558, -0.610334350940889, 
-1.37234525043639, -0.0494515487646545, -0.756125374747801, -1.1302701466249, 
-1.33176524564419, -0.553651972030815), Pi = c(0.317981764865072, 
0.194004855626976, 0.336602397020586, 0.269002371918509, 0.353437060849354, 
0.203426403466547, 0.085013654265328, 0.252021801284264, 0.351982931722769, 
0.202241200193719, 0.487639631600599, 0.319488079759726, 0.244111249748232, 
0.208867522794921, 0.365017539353501), se = c(0.25144350163443, 
0.273182637481648, 0.221088894440468, 0.25265965865359, 0.32514106228583, 
0.321868887860789, 0.843339582594233, 0.261905835743815, 0.202082465844402, 
0.289981426724726, 0.291217371924577, 0.215329401915446, 0.301165703878997, 
0.279681282946346, 0.282823671253511), SeUp = c(0.432849871674714, 
0.291366496245083, 0.439020592793743, 0.376489115034319, 0.508327069687771, 
0.324284213714876, 0.326699339739158, 0.360193869476184, 0.4466407823384, 
0.309174449345777, 0.627459764109079, 0.417248290245548, 0.368190986274075, 
0.313546689950327, 0.500170605899896), SeLo = c(0.221681937544196, 
0.123506825014534, 0.24753428371226, 0.18318696178852, 0.224219940280471, 
0.11963635802375, 0.0174803518597485, 0.167814848755473, 0.267681833971993, 
0.125570002931353, 0.349727415459271, 0.235381214200561, 0.151799699462811, 
0.132395701066921, 0.248246482427503)), row.names = c(374L, 2046L, 
441L, 1348L, 634L, 1652L, 1949L, 1794L, 971L, 2040L, 198L, 587L, 
1471L, 1983L, 653L), class = "data.frame")



> c_neb4_sample <- c_neb4[sample(nrow(c_neb4), 15), ]

> dput(c_neb4_sample)

structure(list(CYR_Keyfield = c("C-2009-7-11-68", "C-2016-7-17-147", 
"C-2012-7-16-156", "C-2019-7-11-135", "C-2018-9-17-159", "C-2010-5-29-122", 
"C-2010-5-29-22", "C-2010-5-29-22", "C-2010-9-5-157", "C-2017-8-13-168", 
"C-2013-5-26-70", "C-2018-9-17-123", "C-2022-8-13-168", "C-2011-9-4-67", 
"C-2017-10-8-123"), Species = c("Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus"), ID = c("2009768_23", "20167147_35", "20127156_20", 
"20197135_21", "20189159_24", "20105122_12", "2010522_15", "2010522_14", 
"20109157_52", "20178168_134", "2013570_2", "20189123_20", "20228168_41", 
"2011967_25", "201710123_122"), SL = c(44.05, 45.66, 45.57, 25.83, 
42.54, 18.48, 26.8, 31.97, 48.41, 17.94, 23.17, 44.63, 28.25, 
21.07, 25.1), empty = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), DateTime = structure(c(1247343360, 1468778940, 1342456800, 
1562867940, 1537209360, 1275138900, 1275143400, 1275143400, 1283705100, 
1502655180, 1369589040, 1537212420, 1660402320, 1315149540, 1507481100
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CYR = c(2009L, 
2016L, 2012L, 2019L, 2018L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2017L, 
2013L, 2018L, 2022L, 2011L, 2017L), Month = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 10L), DoY = c(192, 199, 
198, 192, 260, 149, 149, 149, 248, 225, 146, 260, 225, 247, 281
), ToD = c(16.2666666666667, 14.15, 12.6666666666667, 13.9833333333333, 
14.6, 9.25, 10.5, 10.5, 12.75, 16.2166666666667, 13.4, 15.45, 
10.8666666666667, 11.3166666666667, 12.75), JDay = c(1755, 4318, 
2856, 5407, 5110, 2077, 2077, 2077, 2176, 4710, 3170, 5110, 6536, 
2540, 4766), Station = c(68, 147, 156, 135, 159, 122, 22, 22, 
157, 168, 70, 123, 168, 67, 123), Standard_collection_station = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Latitude = c(25.121, 
25.046, 25.108, 25.036, 25.07, 25.025, 25.056, 25.056, 25.096, 
25.094, 25.132, 25.012, 25.093999961391, 25.134, 25.012), Longitude = c(-80.955, 
-80.91, -80.943, -80.924, -80.907, -80.938, -81.039, -81.039, 
-80.931, -80.905, -80.941, -80.926, -80.9049999620765, -80.967, 
-80.926), Zone = c("West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West"), sal = c(38.7999999999999, 40.74, 37.6, 35.89, 37.67, 
38.1, 36.2, 36.2, 37.5, 43, 41.2, 36.59, 40.4, 37, 32.54), temp = c(30.9, 
30.83, 29.4, 29.763, 32.7839999999998, 30, 30, 30, 31.5, 33.7999999999998, 
27.7, 32.5739999999998, 30.046, 29.8, 29.66), fCYR = structure(c(1L, 
8L, 4L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 14L, 3L, 9L), levels = c("2009", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"), class = "factor"), fStation = structure(c(10L, 
35L, 36L, 29L, 39L, 23L, 3L, 3L, 37L, 41L, 11L, 24L, 41L, 9L, 
24L), levels = c("20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "40", "54", "65", 
"67", "68", "70", "71", "73", "101", "105", "106", "107", "111", 
"112", "117", "118", "119", "122", "123", "124", "130", "133", 
"134", "135", "137", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "156", 
"157", "158", "159", "167", "168", "169", "171", "172", "173", 
"174", "175", "176", "224", "225", "226", "227", "229", "237", 
"239", "240", "241", "253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "265", 
"266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "278", "279", "280", "281", 
"282", "284", "290", "291", "292", "294", "301", "302", "303", 
"304", "312", "313", "315", "323", "609", "619", "621", "622"
), class = "factor"), fZone = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Crocodile", 
"Rankin", "West", "Whipray"), class = "factor"), Season = c("Wet", 
"Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", 
"Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet")), row.names = c(164L, 255L, 
143L, 156L, 178L, 76L, 101L, 93L, 340L, 493L, 3L, 147L, 599L, 
181L, 524L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I can, but it will be a lot. Do you have a suggestion for avoiding the "your question is mostly code" warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't ignore the warning in the `predict` step? You are excluding the *wrong* smooth there.

Of the terms in the model that are *not* shown in the plot you are having difficulty with its the `s(fStation)` ranef term. I never really used *plyr*, but it seems you are generating all combinations of the `fZone`, `fStation` and observed values of `SL` (plus an extra value of `SL` because you also use `evenly()` here?. This would be incorrect for this plot as even though you are removing the effect of the ranef when predicting (or trying to - note the code you show is wrong for this example) you will still have as many rows of data as you have combinations of `fZone`, `fStation` and plus the observed values of `SL`.

Even if my specific diagnosis is incorrect, you clearly have too many data points than needed to generate the plot you want. All you need are `n` evenly spaced values over `SL` for each level of `fZone`, which is `3 * n`.

What you should do is generate the crossing of the levels of `fZone` with the 100 evenly spaced values of `SL`, and after that, add on a column for `fStation` that contains just one level of the random effect, but with the same levels as the original `fStation`. Then predict for this much reduced data frame, while excluding the `s(fStation)` smooth from the predicted values.

I find this most easy to do using functions from my {gratia} package:

```r
ds <- data_slice(m4,
                 SL = evenly(SL, n = 100),
                 fZone = evenly(fZone), # or fZone = levels(fZone)
                 fStation = ref_level(fStation))

fv <- fitted_values(m4, data = ds, exclude = "s(fStation)",
                    scale = "response")
```

The first step creates the data slice for this plot. Note that `evenly()` works for factors, returning the levels of the factor as a factor with the correct levels. `ref_level()` returns the reference (first) level of the factor with levels equal to the levels of the original factor.

The second step there is doing all of your code with `predict()` plus forming the confidence interval on the link/linear predictor scale from the standard errors, and then back transforming to the response scale, but in a single call.

The output from `fitted_values()` is in a form amenable for plotting with `ggplot()`.

Note that if you don't have some of the functions mentioned in the code, you might need to update {gratia}.

Comment: Thank you! How would I tell data_slice that some fStations are only found in certain certain zones (fZone)? i.e fStation 1-10 = zone A, 11-20 = zone B, etc..? The design is "nested"(?), right?

Comment: I don't why that's needed for this question/plot. Short answer, you don't currently; I would just do multiple calls specifying the `fStation` values by hand for each `fZone`. If you want more control, you can just form the data combinations yourself. If these combos are in the observed data, I would just take the distinct rows of your input data and cross that with `SL`

Comment: Oh ok, I wasn't sure if it was important or not for this - I saw some fStations next to the wrong zones in the "ds" dataframe.

Comment: If you saw more than one entry in `fStation` using the code I provided above, then something is wrong; `ref_level()` should only return a single value (the reference level) as a factor (with the same levels as the original)

Comment: I got it to work, only showing 1 station now. Thanks again!